# Implementing a long running service (indefinite length / always available) to handle data in an ASP.NET Core Web Api

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, backgroundworker, background-service

I'm going to try to simplify this,

As part of an ASP.NET Core Web Api (.Net Core 2.2), I am working to achieve a taxi dispatcher background service that runs indefinitely and handles races -> assigns drivers to races, continuously fetch new drivers on the area and assign to races from closest to furthest accordingly (the service reads and writes to different Sql database tables). I created the background service as a hosted service that does all of the above whenever there are races available and handle each race in a new background thread. The api runs on a ftp server on IIS.

**Problem:** It works fine at the beginning but sometimes the service somehow times out and won't handle any incoming races and I have to stop the api and restart it, yikes, which isn't the behavior I want since I want my xamarin-forms app to be responsive and receive races in real time.

After I wrote the service, I started questioning my implementation and I came across terms like *Background worker*, *Microservices* and *Worker services*.. and now I'm more confused on what to fix or how to solve the problem, and if there is a better approach to this.

I use clean architecture design pattern in my Web Api. This is how I register my background service on Program.cs file:

```
        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .ConfigureServices(services =>
                {
                    //Some workaround to use the hostedservice as an API
                    //see https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/553
                    services.AddSingleton<BackgroundManagerService>();
                    services.AddSingleton<IHostedService>(p => p.GetService<BackgroundManagerService>());
                })
                .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    logging.ClearProviders();
                    logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace); //LogLevel.Information
                })
                .UseNLog();  // NLog: Setup NLog for Dependency injection;
```

Help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you realize you haven't asked anything?

Comment: @Gusman I asked if there is a better implementation for what I am trying to achieve (paragraph 3), I'm a noobie to such advanced senario in my opinion :)

Comment: IIS will control the lifetime of your app; it will start the process and will terminate the application pool if the app is idle. Only incoming requests will cause IIS to start the app then. There are a few ways to control this within IIS but I haven’t had a real success in keeping an app always running on IIS.

Comment: @poke There is a way, but it's really crappy: create a static timer that queries your own application each 5-10 minutes, that will prevent the application to be unloaded.

Comment: @poke exactly, it does crash the app pool frequently if the service doesn't terminate (since I don't want to shutdown -> I want it to stay alive and handle races). I read the IIS documentation and couldn't figure out how to refactor my code to keep the service alive. I also recently signed up for an azure account to see if it is the same case but still hoping to run it on iis

Comment: @Gusman thank you for the proposition, I will give it a shot. I hoping to be pointed out to an alternative implementation of the whole service (hosted service) because as of now I am pretty sure I am doing it wrong

Comment: @Anass It was a comment for poke, I would avoid that approach as much as you can. the proper way is to create a microservice: a standalone executable that takes care of these things.

Comment: @Gusman right, thank you for the clarification. I'm still at the beginning of the learning curve of .net core. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Yeah, the “recommended” (as in: working) way to solve this is to host your app as a Windows service instead of through IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into similar issues at work using Hangfire. While you can mess around with idle timeouts and app initializers (https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/deployment-to-production/making-aspnet-app-always-running.html just as an example) we ultimately moved everything into a .NET Core Worker Service and hosted it as a Windows service.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

That is the approach I would suggest, it's worked out very well.

Comment: Thank you @julian for the kind answer and for pointing out your suggestion. I already started reading about Worker Services last week and I should be on my way to achieve what I want to do. I will mark this an answer as soon as I can get demo with the behavior up and running.